# Batch script to find file

Tags: powershell

I need some help with a batch script to recursively find the folder a particular file is in. I have the below PowerShell script which works perfectly fine but I can't get it to run due to execution policy hence I was wondering if anyone can help me convert it to batch file please?

---

```
$val = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{785A2E83-C8B2-46BB-8839-514DE2243EAD}' -Name "DisplayName" -ErrorAction silentlycontinue

if($val.DisplayName -ne 'Internet Explorer 11') {
  $ccmIE11Folders = @(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Windows\ccmcache -Filter IE11-Setup-Full.msi -Recurse)

  If($ccmIE11Folders.count -gt 0)  {
   & "$($ccmIE11Folders[0].DirectoryName)\Install.cmd"
   }
}
```

---

The script first looks for a registry item property. If it does not exist then it recursively finds the file "IE11-Setup-Full.msi" under C:\Windows\CCMCache folder. If found it runs Install.cmd from that resultant folder.

If you wanted to know, we are deploying IE11 in the enterprise using SCCM however a small percentage of them are failing for some unknown reason so I am trying to re-run the installer using this script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -scope Process` prior to running the script?

Comment: I tried that in the batch file just prior to running the powershell script but it throws the below error: Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successf
ully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scop
e.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective execution
 policy of "RemoteSigned". Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execut
ion policy settings. For more information, please see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPo
licy."

   urityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionPolic

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to alter your PS script so that it conforms to the prevailing execution policy.  You could sign the script.

Or, if the script is actually not remote, you could recreate the script locally at the point of execution.  If the script is already stored locally on the computer where it will be executed, but it's still being considered remote, the chances are it was copied from another computer.

When I was faced with this,  I created a new empty .ps1 file with notepad, opened the old script with notepad, copied the whole thing to the clipboard and pasted into the new file.  Presto! the new file was no longer "remote".

Answer (score 0):

You could unblock the cmdfile just before calling it, effectively resetting the flag in it's ADS:

```
    If ($ccmIE11Folders.count -gt 0) {
        $cmd = "$($ccmIE11Folders[0].DirectoryName)\Install.cmd"
        Unblock-File $cmd
        & $cmd
    }
```